# Rust ndarray slicing

Tags: rust, rust-ndarray

I am using `ndarray` and trying to slice some arrays. This works

```
    let y = arr2(&[[ 6,  5,  4],
                   [12, 11, 10]]);
    let ip = y.slice(s![0, ..]);
    println!("IP {}", ip);
```

but this

```
    let y = arr2(&[[ 6,  5,  4],
                   [12, 11, 10]]);
    let ip = y.slice(s![0, ..]);
    println!("IP {}", ip[0]);
```

does not compile. What is going on?

Compile errors are:

```
Error[E0277]: the trait bound `i32: Dimension` is not satisfied 

....

println!("IP {}", ip[0]);
| ^^^^^ the trait `Dimension` is not implemented for `i32`
| = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::ops::Index<i32>` for `ArrayBase<ViewRepr<&i32>, i32>`
```

with other errors

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
....
|         let ip = y.slice(s![0, ..]);
|                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `i32`, found struct `Dim`
|
= note: expected type `i32`
        found struct `Dim<[usize; 1]>`
```

Comment: What does the compiler say?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that integer literals are by default `i32`, and so `ip[0]` tells Rust that `ip: Index<i32>`, which then fixes the type of `slice`'s argument to be `i32`, but the type is supposed to be `impl Dimension`. (I don't fully understand the type hierarchy of `ndarray`'s indices/dimensions, but this is close enough to be useful.) To work around this, simple replace `ip[0]` with `ip[0_usize]`.

Comment: So why does this work then?
               
        let y = arr1(&[[ 6,  5,  4]]);
        println!("Y {:?}", y[0]);

Comment: @CodeyMcCodeface I think it has to do with the details of Rust's type inference. In some instances it *can* infer that `0` should be `0_usize`, but in your case it couldn't so it defaulted to `i32`